# VBA screenupdating in if statement

Tags: vba, excel, combobox, userform

I have a combobox in a userform filled with sheets. If you choose a sheet it activates the sheet so you have the option to unprotect it.

My problem here is if I choose a sheet with the combobox it jumps to that sheet.

I tried to set `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` and `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` in the end and tried it with a `If`-Statement. It doesn't work.

```
Public comBox2 As Boolean
Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()
    Dim sName As String 'name of sheet to show

    comBox2 = True

    sheetName = ComboBox2.Value

    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(sheetName)
        .Activate
    End With
End Sub
Sub Userform_initialize()
    If comBox2 Then
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ElseIf comBox2 = False Then
    comBox2 = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: `combox2` will **always** be `False` in the `Userform_Initialize` event. I don't understand your purpose here - the combobox explicitly activates the sheet, so of course the display switches to it. Why are you activating it, if that's not what you want?

Comment: I thought I have to activate it to make the sheet choosable. is there any other way?

Comment: what do you exactly mean by "choosable"?

Comment: selectable.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Public comBox2 As Boolean
Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()
    Dim sName As String 'name of sheet to show

    comBox2 = True

    sheetName = ComboBox2.Value

End Sub
Sub Userform_initialize()
    If comBox2 Then
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ElseIf comBox2 = False Then
    comBox2 = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End If
End Sub
```

So I deleted that activation of the sheet. Now what I would do is put a button next ti combobox with caption "unprotect" and put code for unprotection in it like:

```
 Activeworkbook.sheets(ComboBox2.value).Unprotect "password" ' in case there is fixed password
```

or if there are different passwords then

```
Dim pass As Variant
pass = InputBox("Password?")
Activeworkbook.sheets(ComboBox2.value).Unprotect pass
```

Comment: You saved my Day! Thanks Captain!

Comment: `ElseIf comBox2 = False Then` can be replaced by `Else`. No need for `comBox2 = False` since we are already in a case where comBox2 is false (tested by the `If... `).

Answer (score 1):

In case that the combobox is in a worksheet, check whether the sheet of the combobox is the active sheet:

```
Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()

    If ComboBox2.Parent.Name = ActiveSheet.Name Then Exit Sub
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(sheetName).Activate

End Sub
```

If it is in a form:

```
Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()

    If ComboBox2.Text = ActiveSheet.Name Then Exit Sub
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(sheetName).Activate

End Sub
```

Comment: not excactly what I wanted but thank you for your effort though!

Comment: Your Code would work very well, but Radek Piekný showed me a way where I don't need to activate the sheet to select the items in it and link it to a button.